Richard Feynman's Definition of Half Derivative
I read from Leonard Mlodinow's Feynman's Rainbow that Feynman has defined the concept of a half-derivative, an operation $g$ on a function $f$ such that
$$g(g(f))=f'.$$
I wonder if it is possible to develop a general rule of finding the half-derivative of any "half-differentiable" function just as finding the derivative of any differentiable function? Furthermore, can we generalize our answers to the previous questions to $\frac{1}{n}$-derivatives?  Can we even defind irrational-derivatives?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Did you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus and the various posts on this site?

@MartinR You're too fast!  I was just about to post the same link. :D  Do note that there is a [tag:fractional-calculus] tag on this site, too.

There are different definitions of the fractional derivative. One important thing though is that they cannot be perfect i.e. their domain cannot cover constant functions w/o breaking the rule
